# Hiding elements behind an ImageMap

Tags: css, html, z-index, imagemap

I am not sure whether i am missing something here, but it seems i cannot put an imagemap above everything else (in terms of z-index). I tried varying the order of the HTML element definition, i tried using CSS to define proper z-index values, but none of these approaches works.

Has anyone encountered similar issues?

(Tested in FF 8.0.1)

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sBSHn/)

Comment: What browser you are testing in? Can you please post example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you post some code or jsfiddle?

Comment: indeed - should have done that right away. added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add position:absolute; to the map too:

http://jsfiddle.net/sBSHn/1/

Comment: Wow, that was simple! Thank you! Will that work across major browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting `#testDiv` to `display:none`

Then whenever the event occurs that you want to trigger it appearing or disappearing simply call:

```
 $('#testDiv').toggle();
```

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use that because it won't conform with the CSS transitions i plan to use.